# Counting character with HashMap

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap, character

I am trying to count all character within a string ("Hello"), but the code is not working. I just don't know how to make the code to do what I want.

Here is why I tried:

```
    char[] array = hello.toCharArray();
    HashMap<Character, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    // hashMap.put('a', 1);
    int occurence = 1;
    char currentChar = ' ';

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        hashMap.put(hello.charAt(i), occurence);
        currentChar = hello.charAt(i);

        for (int j = 0; j < hashMap.size(); j++) {
            if (hashMap.containsKey(currentChar)) {
                hashMap.put(currentChar, occurence + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(hashMap);
}
```

}

However, it just prints all letters with assigned value of 2.

Comment: Welcome to SO! There's no point in iterating over the hashmap (or its size)--that defeats the purpose. Just `get` the key in one call and `put` the new value, no need for the `j` loop. Secondly, `hashMap.put(hello.charAt(i), occurence);` at the top of the loop overwrites whatever previous value was in the map. You only want to do this if the item doesn't exist at all in the map.

Comment: Questions about how to learn programming or how to debug simple code are better suited for [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), in my opinion.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In your code occurence variable is not handled correctly.

single loop should be enough in your case. see below you don't need to use extra variables just get existing count from map itself based on key.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            char currentChar = hello.charAt(i);
            if(hashMap.containsKey(currentChar)) {
                hashMap.put(currentChar,hashMap.get(currentChar)+1);
            }else{
                hashMap.put(currentChar,1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: thank you, it worked like a charm. Now it all makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Java version 8 and above come with lots of powerful map mutating operations

```
    Map<Character,Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();

    for (char c : data.toCharArray())
    {
        counts.merge(c, 1, (oldValue,value)-> oldValue+1 );
    }
```

The merge operation either creates the entry in the map or applies the remapping function to the old value. `v1` is a copy of the second argument in case that is needed in the remapping.  In your case is isn't since the increment is a constant.

Comment: The more idiomatic way to do it would be `counts.merge(c, 1, Integer::sum)`.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Yes, but that works only if the initial value and the increment are the same.  That's because `Integer::sum` will be applied with the old value and the second argument to `merge()`.  It's a subtle point but I can imagine cases where the start value and increment might not both be the same.  In my version it is explicit, whereas with `Integer::sum` it's slightly "magic" to someone less experienced.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
String hello = "Hello there";
Map<Character, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();
for (char c : hello.toCharArray()) {
    count.compute(c, (ch, n) -> n == null ? 1 : n.intValue() + 1);
}
System.out.println(count);
```

It produces

```
{ =1, r=1, t=1, e=3, h=1, H=1, l=2, o=1}
```